# Trying to load Bootstrap calendar on my page. Getting Uncaught Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

The exact error I'm getting is:

> "Uncaught Error: Calendar: Events load URL is not set".

I'm following the instructions on https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar exactly. I'm just trying to get this thing to load so I have an empty body with the line `<div id="calendar"></div>` and my JavaScript contains `var calendar = $('#calendar').calendar();`. When I load the page, though, nothing shows up and the above error shows in my console, pointing me to the JavaScript line. I'm really not quite sure what to do.

Comment: Try setting the URL - even with an empty string...

Comment: @Lix Where/How would I do this?

Comment: It's right there in the page you linked - `$('#calendar').calendar({events_url:'/api/events.php'});`

Comment: Or maybe even passing an empty object - `$('#calendar').calendar({});`

Comment: Ohh, I see. I think I've got to provide it with some data for it to load I guess. I was just hoping to display a blank calendar at first to make sure it loaded correctly

Comment: Looks like it might be a mistake in the documentation. I'm sure if you pass it zero events you'll still get a blank calendar.

Comment: I tried the blank URL and it still didn't display anything. Same error would occur

Comment: Hi... I was having same error .. did u guys finded out the reason behind it ...

Answer (score 5):

The documentation is a little bit misleading.

## To get a demo up and running:

- You need to provide an events-source. You can give it a dummy event source with `events_source: function () { return []; }`.
- You must copy

  - **calendar.min.js** (or calendar.js)
  - **calendar.min.css** (or calendar.css)
  - The **tmpls** folder
- You must load the javascript files [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/), then [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) then [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) and then the calendar in that order.
- It's a good idea to specify the **tmpls path**.

### HTML sample

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/calendar.min.js"></script>

...

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

### Javascript sample

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var calendar = $("#calendar").calendar(
         {
             tmpl_path: "/tmpls/",
             events_source: function () { return []; }
         });
</script>
```

Comment: I was having the same error. Then I notieced that I was using "event_source" instead of "events_source".